# ASP.Net - sending SMTP mail via IIS 7.5 SMTP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, iis-7.5

I have recently configured IIS 7.5 to use the SMTP server.  Now, I have my ASP .Net application that was running in IIS 6 fine, moved over to IIS 7.5.  The website had email functionality, but this has no stopped working.  Has anyone else managed to get IIS 7.5 SMTP working with ASP.Net?

EDIT:
The website is load balanced, would this make a difference?

Comment: Is the SMTP service installed and started?

Comment: Yes, I have checked this and it's installed and started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://forums.iis.net/t/1157046.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have found the solution.  Basically, after stressing out over this for 2 days, it was to do with the Relay configuration.  Added in the necessary IP addresses and it is now working.